# Do infinite sequences always contain consecutive repeated subsequences?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, combinatorics, permutations

Suppose we have some finite set $S$. Suppose we generate an infinitely long sequence $s_n$ from the elements of this set. Is there guaranteed to exist a ''phrase'' from the set $S$ that repeats an arbitrary (but finitely many) times?

More explicitly: is $s_n$ guaranteed to contain a subsequence of length $mk$ where some phrase of length $m$ occurs $k$ times in a row, for arbitrary but finite $m$ and $k$?

For example if $S = \{0,1\}$, for $m=2$, $k=3$, can we be sure that any sequence generated contains at least one of:

- (0,1) repeated: $0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1$
- (1,0) repeated: $1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0$
- (0,0) repeated: $0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0$
- (1,1) repeated: $1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1$

It seems to be correct intuitively but can't find an obvious proof (or disproof).

Comment: I think you mean $mk$, not $m^k$.

Comment: In your own example, what about the sequence 110110110110 etc.?

Comment: @RobertIsrael thank you and corrected - typo!

Comment: Nice suedohnimh you've got there.

Comment: @user21820 5 years for someone to notice ;)

Comment: Wow really? Come find me [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51337/this-is-the-realm-of-simply-beautiful-art). =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Consider the Thue-Morse sequence, whose $n^{th}$ term is $0$ if $n-1$ has an even number of ones in its binary representation, and is $1$ if there are an odd number of ones. This starts like
$$
0,1,1,0,1,0,0,\boxed{1},1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,\dots
$$
For example, the eighth term (boxed above) is a one because $8-1=7$ in binary is $111$, which has an odd number of ones.

It can be shown that the Thue-Morse sequence has no pattern which repeats itself three times consecutively. Therefore, this is a counter-example for any $k\ge 3$.

Answer (score 1):

I think we can prove this by common sense and induction.

Take the set $A = \{s_1,......,s_k\}\subset S$ where $s_i$ are the elements of $S$ that occur an infinite number of times in the sequence, $\{a_i\}$.

Claim: $A$ is not empty. Pf: If it were then all elements of $S$ only occur finitely many times and the sequence would hve to be finite.

If $s_i$ occurs infinitely many times then for any $N$ there is an $n> N$ so that the $n$th term of the sequence, $a_n$, is equal to $s_i$.

Let $\{v_i\}$ be *any* sequence of $A$, repeating or or not.

Claim: There is a subsequence $\{a_{i_m}\} \subset \{a_i\}$ so that $\{a_{i_m}\}=\{v_i\}$.

Pf: As there are infinite number of $v_1 \in \{a_i\}$, ther is an $a_p = v_i$.  Label that as $a_{i_1}$ the first term of the subsequence.

As there are infinite number of $v_2 \in \{a_i\}$ there is an $a_q; p > p$ so that $a_q = v_2$.  Label that as $a_{i_2}$.

When we have gotten any $v_1, v_2,......., v_j = a_{i_1}, a_{i_2},......, a_{i_j}$ terms of the sequence as a subsequence, we just continue: there are infinitely many terms equal to $v_{j+1}$ so there is an $a_\beta \in \{a_i\}$ where $\beta > i_j$ and $a_\beta = v_{j+1}$.  Label that as $a_{i_{j+1}}$ to get the $j+1$st term of the subsequence.  By induction we can get the entire subsequence.

Comment: Thank you - but I might have missed something. The elements of $A$ repeat infinitely - why would the fact they repeat infinitely ensure that a repeated subsequence emerges? I.e. if $A = \{x, y, z\}$ each of those elements will recur but how do we know they will recur in a repeating pattern like say $x, y, x, y, x, y, x, y$?

Comment: As there are infinitely many $y$s and infinitely many $x$s just pick an $x$ there will be a $y$ later.  Pick it.  There will be an $x$ later.  Pick it.  There will by a $y$ later.  pick it.

Comment: @fleablood I think OP is using "subsequence" to mean "consecutive subsequence."

Comment: There must be a term that is $x$.  Mabe it is $a_3$.  There must be a term after that the is equal to $y$.  Maybe it is $a_{27}$.  There most be a term after that that is equal to $x$.  Maybe it is $a_{105}$.  And then there is a term after that will be equal to $y$.  Maybe it is $a_{392}$.  We can do this forever as there are infinitely many $x$ and $y$.  So $a_2, a_{27}, a_{105},a_{392}.....$ is a subsequence that is $x,y,x,y,x,y......$.  If you meant anything else.... the state and ask what you meant.

Comment: Thanks @MikeEarnest I've clarified the question and accepted your answer. Apologies it was unclear before.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the case $m=2$.

Consider the first $8k$ terms of your sequence, divided in $4k$ pairs. 
At least one of the four pairs $(0,0)$, $(0,1)$, $(1,0)$, $(1,1)$ must occur at least $k$ times, otherwise you'd have at most $4(k-1)$ pairs.  Selecting those $k$ pairs, you have
a subsequence of length $2k$ in which one of the four occurs $k$ times.

Generalize to any $m$.

Comment: Thanks very much - would it be possible to elaborate on your second to last line - suppose we have a pair that occurs $k$ times over the $8k$ terms. What is guaranteeing that any two of them would be contiguous?

Comment: I think OP meant "consecutive subsequence."